# camel-netty4-http basic authentication is not working with karaf realm (on karaf container)

Tags: apache-camel

Here are my camel-context and SecurityConstraintMapping bean

```
<bean id="constraint"
        class="org.apache.camel.component.netty4.http.SecurityConstraintMapping">
        <property name="inclusions">
            <map>
                <entry key="/dev/*" value="developer,scrumMaster" />
                <entry key="/test/*" value="tester,scrumMaster" />
                <entry key="/scrum/*" value="scrumMaster" />
            </map>
        </property>
        <property name="exclusions">
            <set>
                <value>/public/*</value>
            </set>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <camelContext id="camelCtx"
        xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">

        <routeBuilder ref="routeBuilder" />

        <route>
            <from
                uri="netty4-http:http://0.0.0.0:{{port}}/dev/ping?matchOnUriPrefix=true&amp;securityConfiguration.realm=karaf&amp;securityConfiguration.securityConstraint=#constraint" />
            <transform>
                <constant>This is ping URL for developer</constant>
            </transform>
        </route>

        <route>
            <from
                uri="netty4-http:http://0.0.0.0:{{port}}/test?matchOnUriPrefix=true&amp;securityConfiguration.realm=karaf&amp;securityConfiguration.securityConstraint=#constraint" />
            <transform>
                <constant>Hello Tester</constant>
            </transform>
        </route>

        <route>
            <from
                uri="netty4-http:http://0.0.0.0:{{port}}/scrum?matchOnUriPrefix=true&amp;securityConfiguration.realm=karaf&amp;securityConfiguration.securityConstraint=#constraint" />
            <transform>
                <constant>Hello Tester</constant>
            </transform>
        </route>

    </camelContext>
```

The path /dev should be accessible to users having roles "developer,srumMaster"

The path /test shuold be accessible to users having roles "tester,srumMaster"

The path /scrum shuold be accessible to users having role "srumMaster" only

The user-role mapping on karaf container is as below

karaf@run()> jaas:user-list

User Name | Group | Role

----------+-------------------+--------------

karaf | admingroup | admin

karaf | admingroup | manager

karaf | admingroup | viewer

karaf | admingroup | systembundles

dev1 | developementGroup | developer

test1 | testGroup | tester

scrum1 | scrumMasterGroup | scrumMaster

scrum1 | scrumMasterGroup | developer

scrum1 | scrumMasterGroup | tester

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not supported by that default constraint as its not integrated with JAAS which is what Karaf uses. So you need to build your own that supports JAAS to get the roles of the user, and then match on those URI patterns.

Comment: Here http://camel.apache.org/netty4-http.html
It is mentioned that it should work on Karaf container out of the box

Comment: Yeah it does, but JAAS authentication is not out of the box. You are welcome to build such a thing and contribute back.